# Concatenating two columns from different tables if one of the columns is not empty

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables which are connected by an ID column (not shown in the picture). Here is how the data looks:

| column1 | column2 |

| -------- | -------------- |

| Mike    | 345            |

| Steve   | 987            |

| Andy   | 0            |

| Lucas   | 0            |

--

| column3 | column4 |

| -------- | -------------- |

| Mike    | 543            |

| Lucas   | 0            |

| Andy   | 678            |

| Steve   | 0            |

I wish to create a calculated column which concatenates the results from the second table in the picture (column3, column4) only if the result in column2 is zero. If the result of column2 is not zero then it should have precedence in concatenation.

Also if both column2 and column4 are zero then there should be no concatenation.

I'm expecting something like this:

| Column3   | Column4    | Concat column|

|---- |------| -----|

| Mike  | 543    | Mike 345 |

| Lucas  | 0    |  |

| Andy  | 678    | Andy 678 |

| Steve  | 0    | Steve 987 |

Comment: You are showing screenshots of non-copyable data and requirements of what others should do for you but it's not visible what effort you yourself put into solving your problem?

Comment: Edited the question so you can see/copy the data. I tried the nested IF/AND but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
ConcatColumn = IF(Table1[Column2]<>0,Table1[Column1]&Table1[Column1],RELATED(Table2[Column3])&RELATED(Table2[Column4]))
```

Before using the above calculated column, First you have to establish relationship Table1 & Table2 by Column1 & Column3.

Also it is assumed that Column2 & Column4 have datatype as **WholeNumber**